# Using try and next in the same step in a GCP Workflow

Tags: google-workflows

What I have:

```
- wait:
    try:
        call: sys.sleep
        args:
            seconds: 5
        next: checkWorkflowInvocationStatus
    except:
        as: e
        <alert on an exception here>
```

The error I get:

> parse error: in workflow 'main', step 'wait': unexpected entry 'next'

It works if I remove the `try`/`except`. Can `next` and `try` really not work together?

Comment: Can you try aligning `next: checkWorkflowInvocationStatus` with `try:` instead of `args:` if this would fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per testing and replication, I've managed to fix it by aligning `next: checkWorkflowInvocationStatus` with `try:` instead of `args:`. My code looks like this:

```
- wait:
    try:
        call: sys.sleep
        args:
            seconds: 5
    next: checkWorkflowInvocationStatus
    except:
        as: e
        <alert on an exception here>
```

Or you may keep the same format and add a name for `call: sys.sleep`, e.g., `sleepStep:`. The code should look like this:

```
- wait:
    try:
      steps:
      - sleepStep:
        call: sys.sleep
        args:
            seconds: 5
        next: checkWorkflowInvocationStatus
    except:
        as: e
        <alert on an exception here>
```